# How to manually navigate to route with React + React-Router-Component

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, reactjs

I've created a React component library, which JS react page views render and control.

```
// Application js, controls the routes.
var Application = React.createClass({
    mixins: [Router],

    routes: {
        '/': HomePage,
        '/users': PerformerPage
        // , null: NotFoundPage
    },

    render: function () {
        return this.transferPropsTo(this.renderRouteHandler());
    }
});

// and in HomeView.js, a link to a page
<Link href={'/users'}>{'Test'}</Link>
```

This all works wondefully. Except when i manually navigate to that link, it clearly doesn't handle it yet... so my question is, if the server redirects to the index ALWAYS, will react catch this? I'm pretty well versed in grunt, and build automation in general, but node js servers aren't my forte yet unfortunately.

In my grunt server

```
  task =>
        'connect:livereload',
        'webpack:development',
        'open',
        'watch'
```

Final result: User should paste address into bar (ie site.com/users) and be navigated to the applications /users.

Thanks :D Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to put the routes in their own file (say client/routes.js)

```
module.exports = {
    '/': HomePage,
    '/users': PerformerPage
    // , null: NotFoundPage
};
```

Now you can require them in your Application file, and in your node server:

```
var app = require('express')();
var routes = Object.keys(require('../client/routes'));

routes.forEach(function(route){
   app.get(route, function(req, res){
      res.sendFile(__dirname + '/static/index.html');
   });
});
```